# CakePHP 3.8.6: Authorization failure when adding new content

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, cakephp-3.8

Given that I am new to CakePHP, I couldn't help but notice a clear failure in Authorization. Again, continuing the [CMS Tutorial](https://book.cakephp.org/3/en/tutorials-and-examples/cms/authentication.html) when I added the code for Authorization and logged in as user1 to the articles/add page, everything was fine. Then I selected the User from a drop down list (after running `cake bake all articles` command and re-modifying the ArticlesController.php as per the tutorial and without modifying the '.ctp files) with user Id = 2, created the article and was able to Save it as well, although I have logged in as user1 with user Id = 1!! I find that weird as well..
    Then I tried to edit user2's articles, it correctly gave an 'Unauthorised access error', but when I tried to edit user1's own articles, it gave the error as follows:

```
Notice (8): Trying to get property 'user_id' of non-object [APP/Controller\ArticlesController.php, line 154]

Warning (512): Unable to emit headers. Headers sent in file=D:\dev\cakePHP\projects\cake_cms\vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\Error\Debugger.php line=856 [CORE\src\Http\ResponseEmitter.php, line 51]

Warning (2): Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at D:\dev\cakePHP\projects\cake_cms\vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\Error\Debugger.php:856) [CORE\src\Http\ResponseEmitter.php, line 152]

Warning (2): Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at D:\dev\cakePHP\projects\cake_cms\vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\Error\Debugger.php:856) [CORE\src\Http\ResponseEmitter.php, line 181]

Warning (2): Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at D:\dev\cakePHP\projects\cake_cms\vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\Error\Debugger.php:856) [CORE\src\Http\ResponseEmitter.php, line 181]

Warning (2): Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at D:\dev\cakePHP\projects\cake_cms\vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\Error\Debugger.php:856) [CORE\src\Http\ResponseEmitter.php, line 181]
```

The code corresponding to the error message (ArticlesController.php, line 154) is as follows:

```
public function isAuthorized($user)
{
    $action = $this->request->getParam('action');
    // The add and tags actions are always allowed to logged in users.
    if (in_array($action, ['add', 'tags'])) {
        return true;
    }

    // All other actions require a slug.
    $slug = $this->request->getParam('pass.0');
    if (!$slug) {
        return false;
    }

    // Check that the article belongs to the current user.
    $article = $this->Articles->findBySlug($slug)->first();

<**line 154**>    return $article->user_id === $user['id'];
}
```

This means that the Edit function is not working no matter which user is logged in.

```
So here is my question:
```

1. How does the Authorization work when one user, say user1, tries to save an article with User Id other than himself?
2. Why does the Authorization code not allow user1 to edit his own article?

Thanks in advance,
Swroop

Comment: `$article` is not an object, figure out what exactly it is and go from there. If it's `null`, then there is no article with the given slug.

Answer (score 0):

The failure message (line 154) indicates that `$article` never got the right value it was supposed to which implies that `$slug` never got the right value, although a non-zero value. I found the problem. It turns out that I am using find by Id (auto code generation) and not `findBySlug()` in the `edit()` code as suggested in the article, so a call to the function `$slug = $this->request->getParam('pass.0');` returns the Id of the article and not the `$slug` value. If a person is using `bin\cake bake all articles` command to autogenerate most of code, it comes with find by Id and not `findBySlug()`. Hence the authorization code should look as follows:

```
    public function isAuthorized($user)
    {
        $action = $this->request->getParam('action');
        // The add and tags actions are always allowed to logged in users.
        if (in_array($action, ['add', 'tags'])) {
            return true;
        }

        // All other actions require a slug.
        $id = $this->request->getParam('pass.0');
        if (!$id) {
            return false;
        }

        // Check that the article belongs to the current user.
        $article = $this->Articles->get($id);

        return $article->user_id === $user['id'];
    }
```

With the above change, only the Authorized user is allowed to edit, preventing all other users.

This answers only the second question, first question still remains open.